# How to make a new GitHub repo of the local with same commit history?

Tags: git, github

I am a newbie to Git and GitHub. I know the basic cloning, pushing, and merging. I want to be good at Git so I decided to track my code using Git.

I made a local repo of my code. I have done 3 commits until now. I created a new repo on GitHub and tried to push the changes but they won't merge because of the different commit history, I don't want to complicate things so, I deleted the repo on Github.

I want to push my local repo with all the commits to a new remote in Github. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but they won't merge because of the different commit history

I **guess**, you have chosen any of the checkboxes while creating a repository in GitHub:
[image: Initialize this repository with a README or .gitignore or license]

This will make your remote repository NOT empty, with files / commits not exist in your local repository. That is when the "different commit history" generated.

For solution, you should

1. create a repository WITHOUT any ticks in this picture
2. Or, if your remote repository has nothing important, you can OVERWRITE it with `-f` parameter for `git push`, for example `git push -f origin master` or something equivalent.

Comment: yes, I had created a readme file in my new GitHub repo. I knew that was the problem so I decided to push the GitHub repo to local. It pushed somehow but it got two different branch master and main. After that I decided to merge both but it failed, I tried to rebase but it also failed, I even tried the -f but "fatal error " because of different history?

Comment: @jigzflue Many questions here.

Comment: "but it got two different branch master and main", the default branch of Git is named "master" in history, but it modified into "main" after BLM movement. Git has a config `init.defaultBranch` to control. GitHub has a config https://github.com/settings/repositories to control. And you can rename branch by `git branch -m`. Check all the settings, and normalize them.

Comment: "I tried to rebase but it also failed", you should post the detailed message for debugging. "I even tried the -f but "fatal error " because of different history?", still, you need to post a detailed log.

Comment: I will learn as I advance in Git, but your advice really helped me. the issue is solved I created a new repo with nothing and then pushed the changes into it.